# "Please stop berating the mods" -- should we start doing this or what?

Tags: discussion

https://superuser.com/users/707676/attie said "please stop berating the mods" to me in [setting up external 1TB SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/1550300/setting-up-external-1tb-ssd#comment2357595_1550300) . I made ***no single comment about the mods*** (at least, in their function as the mods; I don't need to know their user names) in that very post, so, I flagged the Attie's comment as inappropriate. But, it's still there.  What is wrong with that user?  I edited my question several times to make clear what I mean, I flagged a comment or two, but I did ***nothing wrong***.

I feel really angry and offended by such a poisonous comment, since the comment has nothing to do with the technical question on the external drive.  If a user god knows why feels that I berate the mods, they better choose some other means to tell me or keep silent, but what they wrote in a comment has nothing to do with the technical question at hand and is highly inappropriate.

Comment: Fine. For information there are four missing deleted comments that may be what is being referred to by the original comment. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmXX3.png

Comment: @Mokubai Fine. But I have not addressed the users in their function as moderators (if they are moderators at all), have I?

Answer (score 6):

Pinging every one who voted to close *can* be a little annoying - and might be seen as impolite - which is what the OP was trying to get it. Folks might sometimes not be *that* gentle on points of site

The first edit on any closed posts throws it into the reopen queue anyway - so trying to ping *each and every* closevoter isn't desirable.

In the old days, and you still could, folks could/would get attention for a post by making a case on meta, and this might be an option here if you felt your improvements are compelling.